# How can I use jQuery with Laravel and Ajax to update a div's price based on a user-selected shipment service?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i have input select like this :

```
<div class="mb-4 pb-2">
       <select class="form-select" id="shipment-price" required
       @if(Cart::content()->isEmpty()) disabled @endif>
          <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">- Select Delivery Service -</option>
       @forelse ($shipment as $shipping)
          <option value="{{ $shipping->id }}">{{ $shipping->name }} ({{ presentPrice($shipping->price) }})</option>
       @empty
          <option value="0">-</option>
       @endforelse
       </select>
    </div>
```

and div like this

```
<div class="row justify-content-between">
       <div class="col">
           <p class="mb-1"><b>Shipping</b></p>
       </div>
       <div class="flex-sm-col col-auto">
           <p class="mb-1"><b id="shipping-value">Rp. 0</b></p>
       </div>
   </div>
```

i want to update div price to use user selected shipment service

Rp. 0

when user select the shipment service, can somebody help me ??

Comment: You can use jQuery `onChange`, then call the service from laravel and append the response value on the div

Comment: can you gimme example to change that using jquery ?? im newb and still learning to using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onChange` of `shipment-price`, you would have a route to return the `shipment value`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#shipment-price').on('change', function(e){ //on change of shipment-price 
        let shipmentValue = $('#shipment-price').val(); // the dropdown item selected value
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType : 'json', 
            url : "{{route('pricevalue', ['id'=>"+shipmentValue+"])}}",
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data.status){ //from your response 
                    $('#shipping-value').val(data.amount) // you can check the console to be sure of the response  
                }
            },error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            },
        })
    });
})
```

Your route would look like:

```
Route::get('/get-shipment-price/{id}', [ShipmentController::class, 'getShipmentPrice'])->name('pricevalue');
```

While your `getShipmentPrice` function in `YourController` would look like:

```
public function getShipmentPrice(Request $request)
    {
        $shipmentPrice = Shipment::where('shipment-type', $request->id)->first();
        if ($shipmentPrice) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,  'data' => $shipmentPrice
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false, 'message' => 'Error',
        ]);
    }
```